# Automatically filing emails in Gmail

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

In Gmail I can select an email and "Move to ASD" but I want to be able to do this automatically for new emails (that match certain criteria). I would want it to be "automatically marked as read" as well (since like doing filing).

Has anyone tried it before?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a filter (see [here](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6579) if you don't know how) that applies the label ASD and select 'Skip the Inbox'

Comment: heys btw i would want it to be "automatically marked as read" as well (since i'm like doing filing here), is there a way to do it?

Comment: @pacerier, it's in the filter settings (the second option on the what to do with the matches page)